# Query does not return all records

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]below is my query and i am willing to fetch all doctor and their no of appointment per months

```
select d.doctorFName,d.doctorLName ,count(ap.appointmentID) totalap,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  s.speciality) specialities
FROM  tbl_doctors d
INNER JOIN  tbl_doctor_speciality  ds ON (d.doctorID = ds.doctorID)
INNER JOIN tbl_speciality  s ON (s.spID = ds.spID)
Inner join tbl_appointment ap on (ap.doctorID = d.doctorID)
Inner join tbl_patients p on p.patientID = ap.patientID 
GROUP BY d.doctorID
```

and i am willing to fetch records by

```
DATE_FORMAT(ap.appDate, '%Y-%m') = '2013-10'
```

if some one doctors not any appointment for specific months then return 0 for doctor row,how i can do this?

my desire out put

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as shown below. If you need more help, you need to post some sample data and your desired output.

```
SELECT d.doctorFName,
    d.doctorLName,
    count(ap.appointmentID) totalap,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  s.speciality) specialities,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(ap.appDate) = 2013 AND MONTH(ap.appDate) = 10 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 END) Oct2013,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(ap.appDate) = 2013 AND MONTH(ap.appDate) = 11 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 END) Nov2013,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(ap.appDate) = 2013 AND MONTH(ap.appDate) = 12 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 END) Dec2013
FROM  tbl_doctors d
    INNER JOIN  tbl_doctor_speciality  ds ON (d.doctorID = ds.doctorID)
    INNER JOIN tbl_speciality  s ON (s.spID = ds.spID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_appointment ap on (ap.doctorID = d.doctorID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_patients p on p.patientID = ap.patientID 
GROUP BY d.doctorID
```

Comment: please check sample data

Comment: @MuhammadRashid Try the updated query, I have written the query to calculate the appointments for Oct, Nov and Dec of 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Try Left Join on Appt table

```
SELECT d.doctorFName,d.doctorLName ,count(ap.appointmentID) totalap,
     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  s.speciality) specialities,DATE_FORMAT(ap.appDate, '%Y-%m') appMonth
FROM  tbl_doctors d
INNER JOIN  tbl_doctor_speciality  ds ON (d.doctorID = ds.doctorID)
INNER JOIN tbl_speciality  s ON (s.spID = ds.spID)
LEFT JOIN tbl_appointment ap on (ap.doctorID = d.doctorID)
INNER JOIN tbl_patients p on p.patientID = ap.patientID 
GROUP BY d.doctorID,appMonth
```

This will first show grouped by Dr and then grouped by appDate month...
If a Dr has no appt for a month it would show zero 
I believe this work for you

Comment: Rashid, answer has also been modified have a look